# How to cache a mongoose query in memory?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, mongoose

I have the following queries, which starts with the GetById method firing up, once that fires up and extracts data from another document, it saves into the race document.

I want to be able to cache the data after I save it for ten minutes. I have taken a look at cacheman library and not sure if it is the right tool for the job. what would be the best way to approach this ?

```
 getById: function(opts,callback) {
        var id = opts.action;
        var raceData = { };
        var self = this;

        this.getService().findById(id,function(err,resp) {
                    if(err)
                        callback(null);
                    else {

                            raceData = resp;                            

                            self.getService().getPositions(id, function(err,positions) {    
                                    self.savePositions(positions,raceData,callback);                                    
                            });
                    }
        });
  },

  savePositions: function(positions,raceData,callback) {
        var race = [];
    _.each(positions,function(item) {                           
          _.each(item.position,function(el) {
            race.push(el);
        });   
    });

        raceData.positions = race;  

        this.getService().modelClass.update({'_id' : raceData._id },{ 'positions' : raceData.positions },callback(raceData));

  }
```

Comment: Look into the `node-cache` npm package. The `stdTTL` option allows you to set the duration before the cache expires.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently coded and published a module called Monc. You could find the source code over [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monc). You could find several useful methods to store, delete and retrieve data stored into the memory.

You may use it to cache Mongoose queries using simple nesting as

```
test.find({}).lean().cache().exec(function(err, docs) {
  //docs are fetched into the cache.
});
```

Otherwise you may need to take a look at the core of Mongoose and override the prototype in order to provide a way to use [cacheman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cacheman-mongo) as you original suggested.

Create a node module and force it to extend Mongoose as:

```
monc.hellocache(mongoose, {});
```

Inside your module you should extend the `Mongoose.Query.prototype`

```
exports.hellocache = module.exports.hellocache = function(mongoose, options, Aggregate) {

  //require cacheman 

  var CachemanMemory = require('cacheman-memory');
  var cache = new CachemanMemory();

  var m = mongoose;
  m.execAlter = function(caller, args) {
    //do your stuff here
  }

  m.Query.prototype.exec = function(arg1, arg2) {
        return m.execAlter.call(this, 'exec', arguments);
    };
})
```

Take a look at [Monc's source code](https://github.com/vorillaz/monc/blob/master/lib/mongoose.js#L224) as it may be a good reference on how you may extend and chain Mongoose methods

Answer (score 0):

I will explain with npm redis package which stores key/value pairs in the cache server. keys are queries and redis stores only strings.

we have to make sure that keys are unique and consistent. So key value should store query and also name of the model that you are applying the query.

when you query, inside the mongoose library, there is

```
function Query(conditions, options, model, collection) {} //constructor function
```

responsible for query. inside this constructor,

```
Query.prototype.exec = function exec(op, callback) {}
```

this function is responsible executing the queries. so we have to manipulate this function and have it execute those tasks:

first check if we have any cached data related to the query
if yes respond to request right away and return
if no  we need to respond to request and update our cache and then respond

```
const redis = require("client");
const redisUrl = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379";
const client = redis.createClient(redisUrl);
const util = require("util");
//client.get does not return promise
client.get = util.promisify(client.get);

    const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;
   //mongoose code is written using classical prototype inheritance for setting up objects and classes inside the library.

mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function() {
  //crate a unique and consistent key
  const key = JSON.stringify(
    Object.assign({}, this.getQuery(), {
      collection: this.mongooseCollection.name
    })
  );
  //see if we have value for key in redis
  const cachedValue = await redis.get(key);
  //if we do return that as a mongoose model.
  //the exec function expects us to return mongoose documents
  if (cachedValue) {
    const doc = JSON.parse(cacheValue);
    return Array.isArray(doc)
      ? doc.map(d => new this.model(d))
      : new this.model(doc);
  }
  const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments); //now exec function's original task.
  client.set(key, JSON.stringify(result),"EX",6000);//it is saved to cache server make sure capital letters EX and time as seconds
};
```

if we store values as array of objects we need to make sure that each object is individullay converted to mongoose document.
`this.model` is a method inside the Query constructor and converts object to a mongoose document.

note that if you are storing nested values instead of client.get and client.set, use client.hset and client.hget

Now we monkey patched 
Query.prototype.exec

so you do not need to export this function. wherever you have a query operation inside your code, mongoose will execute above code